# How to emit only last request in subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I send a form using complex logic inside `concatMap` operator. And all works fine, but in my subscribe method I have additional http requests, which fires 2 times instead of 1. I tried to use `takeLast` operator, but it didn't help. I need to make requests in subscribe method only after all requests completed in `concatMap`.
For example, if I have two `updateMember()` events, after each request I get invoked function from subscribe method.

```
makeRequest(value) {
  const team = toFormData(this.form.controls.profile.value);

  this.teamService
  .sendTeam(team)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      const tasks$ = [];

      for (const [index, m] of this.form.controls.members.value.entries()) {
        const member = toFormData(m);

        if (m.id) {
          tasks$.push(this.teamService.updateMember(member, m.id).pipe(take(1)));
        } else if (!member.entries().next().done) {
          if (member.has('name')) {
            tasks$.push(this.teamService.createMember(member).pipe(take(1)));
          } else {
            (this.form.controls.members as FormArray).controls[index].markAllAsTouched();
            this.scrollToFirstInvalidControl();
          }
        }
      }

      return tasks$.length ? concat(...tasks$) : EMPTY;
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(() => {

    this.teamService.getMembers().subscribe();

  });
}
```

What should I use to make only necessary requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `takeLast` was a good idea, but it's important where you place it:

```js
this.teamService
  .sendTeam(tem)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      /* ... */

      return tasks.length ? concat(...tasks).pipe(last()) : EMPTY;
    }),

    // You can avoid to manually subscribe in the `subscribe`'s callback
    switchMap(() => this.teamService.getMembers())
  ).subscribe()
```

`concatMap` subscribes to the an observable resulted from calling the provided callback function.

In this case, that observable can either be `concat(...tasks).pipe(last())` or `EMPTY`.

If it's `concat(...tasks).pipe(last())`, it will wait for each `task` to complete. `last` also uses `takeLast(1)` internally.

By the way, `concat` can be seen this way:

```js
// concat(observables[])

from(observables[])
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(obs$ => obs$, 1)
  )
```

If it's `EMPTY`, it will immediately send a complete notification, meaning that `teamService.getMembers()` from  `switchMap(() => this.teamService.getMembers())` won't be invoked.

Comment: for example I have variable successSubmit, how can I change a value, if non of tasks in concatMap won't be invoked?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? If a the tasks won't be invoked, it means that `EMPTY` will be chosen, right?

Comment: yes. Shortly, I have a success message for user, when form submited, I want to change the variable when the request is completed. I put a code in subscribe. `successSubmit = true`. If request contains tasks$, it's alright, the value is set, but when only sendTeam works. nothing happens

Comment: Hmm, I think you can detect whether `EMPTY` was chosen or not by adding this after `concatMap()`: `(isEmpty(), tap(isEmpty => this.submit = !isEmpty))`. `isEmpty` is true if `EMPTY` was chosen. Note that this presumes that `teamService.sendTeam` completes

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any value from sendTeam, you're only waiting for the completion so you can subscribe to the response an then process your data.

```
makeRequest(value) {
  const team = toFormData(this.form.controls.profile.value);
  new Observable(subscription => {
    this.teamService
    .sendTeam(team)
    .subscribe(() => {
      const tasks$ = [];
        for (const [index, m] of this.form.controls.members.value.entries()) {
          const member = toFormData(m);

          if (m.id) {
            tasks$.push(this.teamService.updateMember(member, m.id).pipe(take(1)));
          } else if (!member.entries().next().done) {
            if (member.has('name')) {
              tasks$.push(this.teamService.createMember(member).pipe(take(1)));
            } else {
              (this.form.controls.members as FormArray).controls[index].markAllAsTouched();
              this.scrollToFirstInvalidControl();
            }
          }
        }

        subscription.next(tasks$.length ? concat(...tasks$) : EMPTY);
    });
  }).subscribe(() => {

    this.teamService.getMembers().subscribe();

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the data structure you are looking for is the ReplySubject. It will act as a Subject and will store the last emitted value.